# Copy all attributes from custom element into template in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

When you are creating a custom element in Aurelia, is there a way to take all of the extra attributes that aren't bound and copy them to a specific element inside the template.  For example, say I create a custom element called "my-custom-element" with a bindable property called "name".

```
<my-custom-element name="MyName" class="my-class" data-id="1" />
```

My template would be the following:

```
<template>
    <input name.bind="name" type="text" />
</template>
```

What I would like to have rendered is:

```
<input name="MyName" class="my-class" data-id="1" />
```

So in other words I would like any addition attribute(s) that isn't put in by Aurelia or isn't bound to a property to be available for me add to an element in my template. I could add a bindable property for class because that is pretty common, something like the "data-" attributes could be anything.

I would also like to see if it can support the a containerless custom element.

Answer (score 0):

It's just HTML, so you could probably inject the element itself in to the VM for the custom element, and then ref the `input` element. Then you'd use plain old DOM methods to inspect the custom element. It'd probably be a bit brittle, but something like the below should work:

```
import {inject, customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('my-custom-element')
@inject(Element)
export class MyCustomElement {
  @bindable name;

  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  attached() {
    const attributes = this.el.attributes;

    for( const attr of attributes ) {
      let {name, value} = attr;

      if(name != 'au-target-id') {
        const dotLocation = name.indexOf('.');

        if( dotLocation > -1 ) {
          name = name.substring(0, dotLocation);
        }

        if(name !== 'name') {
          this.myInput.setAttribute(name,value);
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I've created a runnable gist [here](https://gist.run/?id=6f9bd949ce5db6dbe45bcfb6f8ef548f&sha=5c71e9a13ce6cdf51599afa77961b3741d9a861d).

Comment: Thanks!  This is pretty close.  If I make it containerless, it no longer works.  Is there a way to support a containerless custom element?

Comment: I doubt it, but honestly I think people overuse containerless. It should only be used if it is ABSOLUTELY necessary.

Comment: Yea, I get what you are saying.  The reason I ask is because those same attributes will exist on the root element.  So anyone who is writing javascript or css looking for specific attributes will have to know to specify the specific template element.  So in the example I gave it has a css class.  If I just add a style for .my-class it will associate that style to both elements.

Comment: Change your css 

Comment: Yea, that is an option.  I was just hoping we wouldn't have to do that.  :)

Comment: I'll give you the advice that a wise senior dev gave me when I was a junior dev: "If you're doing something and it starts to become overly difficult, maybe you should take a step back and figure out if your entire approach is wrong. Because it probably is."